# When a CAAnimation is autoreversed is the timingFunction reversed too?

Tags: ios, caanimation

**An example:** The following will **ease-in** the alpha from 0 to 1. When it reverses will it **ease-in** from 1 to 0, or will it *reverse* the timing function, and essentially use **ease-out**?

```
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"alpha"];
animation.fromValue = @0;
animation.toValue = @1;
animation.duration = 1.0;
animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction easeIn];
animation.autoreverses = YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the reversed animation **does** use a reversed timing function!

So in the above example:

`0.0` –> `1.0` is **eased in**

`1.0` –> `0.0` is **eased out**.

Comment: Interesting question and the corresponding discovery; how were you able to ascertain that it does use a reversed timing function? I wager that this has to do with trigonometric functions. You got me curious.

Comment: @Unheilig I figured it out empirically by animating a view to move across the screen over a long period using `easeIn` timing and `autoreverse`; from this it was clear that the view had it's highest velocity *just before* and *after* autoreversing, leading me to believe that the timing function is just used in reverse :)

Comment: :-), epic, just what I thought - you eyeballed it. ;-) Interesting question +1. Thanks for response.

Comment: @Unheilig happy to share!